# Open source Computer Algebra System (CAS)

Tags: python, math

I am looking for an open-source CAS based on python. However, I want this CAS to be able to take natural language (ex: "1+(5^2)" or "integrate x^2 from 0 to 1" or "one times 5") and return a result. I have been looking into sympy's parser, which is close to what I want, but sympy's parser is limited in its natural language processing abilities. Does anybody know of such a program or Python module?